# mantener formato en celda en datagridview c#

Tags: c#

Buenas noches:
Tengo un datagridview (dgv) donde la columna "Precio" tiene el formato "N2" definido en la propiedad DefaultCellStyle del dgv.
Cuando cambio el valor de la celda Precio se pierde el formato.
Por ejemplo, cuando coloco 5 debería quedar 5.00 y no 5.
Cómo puedo hacer para mantener el formato?
Gracias

Comment: Hice una prueba tal cual describes, y funciona perfectamente. La asignación del estilo la hice por código desde `Form_Load`

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET  Cómo podría hacer para que las celdas se muevan de izquierda a derecha en vez de arriba a abajo, cada vez que le doy Enter? Gracias

Comment: Aquí sólo se responde por el problema de la pregunta, pero una forma de intercambiar teclas en `DataGridView` se explica en [este link de msdn.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdialogkey.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias aplicar el formato al valor ingresado en el evento [CellEndEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex);
        cell.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(cell.Value).ToString("N2");
    }

}
```

Comment: El autor lo necesita en c#

Comment: tienes razon edito el codigo

Comment: Gracias Leandro. Me funcionó a la perfección. Sólo que ahora tengo otro detalle: cuando le doy Enter a la celda se queda allí y no pasa a la sgte a pesar que tengo el KeyPreview=.T. en mi form.  Tengo que presionar TAB. Tengo el método que me convierte el Enter en Tab (ver al final) pero nada. En el DGV tengo la propiedad EditMode = EditOnEnter. Tendrá algo que ver? Gracias          private void Frm_Keypress(...)  {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }

Comment: Leandro, ya lo solucione. Esto ocurría sólo en la celda de la última fila. Las de arriba si bajan a la siguiente cuando le doy Entero estando el EditMode en EditOnEnter. Gracias

Comment: Dice "Entero" Debe decir "Enter"

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
int num = 5;
float resultado;
resultado = formato(num);

    private static float formato(int numero)
    {
        String numformat = numero.ToString() + "." + "00";
        return float.Parse(numformat);
    }
```

Comment: en que evento pondria este codigo?, ademas tienes el N2 para aplicar formato no necesitas concatenar un string

Comment: Seria un método dentro de tu clase, que al llamarla y pasarle tu numero te devolvería tu numero formateado como tu desees, si le pasas un 5 te deberia devolver un 5.00

Comment: Gracias de todos modos Fran pero usé la sugerencia de Leandro y me fue bien. Saludos

Comment: Me alegro, de eso se trata de encontrar soluciones ;)